# Toolbar search customization

Tags: search, toolbar, codenameone

I added the new toolbar search in my app, which is awesome. I have some questions regarding it.

How can I remove the cancel icon (x) in the right of the search toolbar?

Also, since the transition is not very smooth between the app toolbar and search toolbar, how can I set the `animatelayout` etc when I close or go back to the search toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

Currently neither one of those can be customized but it should be pretty easy to do your own custom search support without those. This is discussed in the [Toolbar](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Toolbar.html) javadoc:

```
Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);
Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Title");

Form hi = new Form("Toolbar", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
TextField searchField = new TextField("", "Toolbar Search"); // <1>
searchField.getHintLabel().setUIID("Title");
searchField.setUIID("Title");
searchField.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Component.LEFT);
hi.getToolbar().setTitleComponent(searchField);
FontImage searchIcon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_SEARCH, s);
searchField.addDataChangeListener((i1, i2) -> { // <2>
    String t = searchField.getText();
    if(t.length() < 1) {
        for(Component cmp : hi.getContentPane()) {
            cmp.setHidden(false);
            cmp.setVisible(true);
        }
    } else {
        t = t.toLowerCase();
        for(Component cmp : hi.getContentPane()) {
            String val = null;
            if(cmp instanceof Label) {
                val = ((Label)cmp).getText();
            } else {
                if(cmp instanceof TextArea) {
                    val = ((TextArea)cmp).getText();
                } else {
                    val = (String)cmp.getPropertyValue("text");
                }
            }
            boolean show = val != null && val.toLowerCase().indexOf(t) > -1;
            cmp.setHidden(!show); // <3>
            cmp.setVisible(show);
        }
    }
    hi.getContentPane().animateLayout(250);
});
hi.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar("", searchIcon, (e) -> {
    searchField.startEditingAsync(); // <4>
});

hi.add("A Game of Thrones").
        add("A Clash Of Kings").
        add("A Storm Of Swords").
        add("A Feast For Crows").
        add("A Dance With Dragons").
        add("The Winds of Winter").
        add("A Dream of Spring");
hi.show();
```

[image]